# Where to ask about repurposing hardware?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a SIM card that I don't feel like throwing away. I know that you can store contacts on it, so I figured that it could be used as an external storage device (you can't ever have too many external drives).

All internet searches on "uses for old SIM cards" yield mostly irrelevant results (using old SIMs in new phones) and those that are relevant are on sites such as Quora or Yahoo! Answers where there isn't really a theme/central topic like there is on SE sites. Also, all the answers are really low tech ("sell it (for the gold)", "I use my SIM cards as bookmarks", etc).

Searching SE only yields results about putting old SIMs in new phones, managing contacts, etc.

I really want to make some use out of this SIM card, so I wanted to know what the rest of the SE community thought.

The question title will probably be "Uses for old SIM cards".

This isn't really a hardware *recommendation*; it has nothing to do with computers (so not SU); it's not programming either (so not SO). So where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a *specific* purpose, this question is going to be "Too Broad" or "Primarily Opinion Based" on any SE site.

However, if you have a specific project in mind, and need help to get it working, there is a [SIM tag](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sim) on Electronics Engineering SE.

Note that there isn't much memory on a SIM card. An SD card will give you much more memory at a comparable size and weight.

If you're just looking for ideas, you could look for a chat room that is open to discussions of ideas / brainstorming.

Comment: What if I changed the title to "Use SIM card as storage device"? Would that still be on topic for said tag on said SE site?

Comment: @Arc676 I think it would still be too broad. You could ask if it's on-topic on their meta or chat first.

Comment: @Arc676 I'm a regular on EE.SE and agree 100% with all S.L. Barth has said. Interfacing one to a PC would be relatively complex for a novice (hence too broad) unless you were most of the way already. Also from a practical point of view there's no way you'd build a reader/writer for less than the $2-3 they cost on e-bay unless you already had most of the parts already sitting about.